# Sending mail with NodeJS and Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

So I've created a form to send a mail. It is something like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 form-group">
    <input class=" form-control " requried style="border-radius:20px" ng-model="name" name="name" type="text"  />
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 form-group">
    <input class="form-control border-radius" required style="border-radius:20px" id="email" name="email" type="email" ng-model="email"  />
</div>
</div>
<textarea class="form-control" id="message" style="border-radius:20px" name="message"  rows="5" ng-model="message"></textarea>
<br />
<div class="row">
    <div  class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 form-group">
    <button ng-click="send(ngCart.getCart().items,message,email,name)" id="send_email" class="btn btn-primary pull-right btn-color" type="submit" style="border-radius:20px">send</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The ng-click send functions looks like this in the controller:

```
  $scope.send = function (items, message, email, name) {

            if (email == undefined) {
                alert("Error!")
            }
            else
            {
                var data = email; 
                var config = {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
                    }
                }

                $http.post('/send', data, config)
                    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.PostDataResponse = data;
                        console.log("Is working", data, status, headers, config);
                    })
                    .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
                        $scope.ResponseDetails = "Data: " + data +
                            "<hr />status: " + status +
                            "<hr />headers: " + header +
                            "<hr />config: " + config;
                    });
            }


        };
    }])
```

and in NodeJS I have the following:

```
app.post('/send', function(req,res){
  console.log("Api Req: ",req);
  console.log("Api Res: ",res);
    var mailOptions={
        from : "from@mail.com",
        to : "test@mail.com",
        subject : "Your Subject",
        text : "Your Text",
        html : "HTML GENERATED"
    }
    console.log(mailOptions);
    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
            res.end("error");
        }else{
            console.log(response.response.toString());
            res.end("sent");
        }
    });
});
```

now the issue is in NodeJS I can not see the data I want to send in the angular Function (ngCart.getCart().items,message,email,name) in req or res, why is that?

EDIT:
It does send the mail with the fixed data as seen above when visiting localhost/send but it can not get data from the send function and I just can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request payload is located in `req.body`.

Comment: Ok, I've Figured it out, it returns the body know however it is in this format:

Body  { '{"formdata":{"email":"test@mail.com","message":"asdasd"},"cart":[{"_id":"2","_name":"asdadasd","_price":9.99,"_quantity":1}]}': '' }

seems like a string, why didn't it parse to json?